# How to auto play an MP4 animation on loop without any control using exoplayer3 and latest jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to have a short mp4 clip from res/raw to be autoplayed as background video with no controls in loop.

How to do that in jetpack compose latest version ?

I tried using exoplayer.

```
@Composable
fun ExoplayerExample() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri("android.resource://" + LocalContext.current.packageName + "/" + R.raw.my_video)
        .build()
    val exoPlayer = remember(context, mediaItem) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build()
            .also { exoPlayer ->
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                exoPlayer.repeatMode = REPEAT_MODE_ONE
            }
    }

    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(factory = {
            PlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer,


            }
        })
    ) {
        onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
    }
}
```

Isn't there any video compose?